# Why is zsh reading new lines (^M) in ~/.zshrc as commands?

Tags: shell, terminal, newline, zsh, zshrc

I'm not sure what I did to mess up my zsh configuration but every time I try to run zsh I get the following message followed by the default theme:

```
/Users/danny/.zshrc:3: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:9: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:13: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:16: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:19: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:22: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:25: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:28: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:32: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:33: command not found: ^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:source:34: no such file or directory: /Users/danny/.oh-my-zsh^M/oh-my-zsh.sh^M
/Users/danny/.zshrc:35: command not found: ^M
danny%
```

I've tried removing .zshrc and .oh-my-zsh and reinstalling oh-my-zsh via brew but I continue to have the same issue. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because CR isn't considered a newline, only LF. Use `dos2unix` on your file, and only edit it with a text editor that can tell the difference.

Comment: Ok great, this seems to solve the issue for ~/.zshrc but now I'm seeing it in ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh and other places. Is there a global setting somewhere that is reading everything in the wrong format?

Comment: @DannyGarcia I belive there are no. But where did you get oh-my-zsh? Maybe this is your VCS misconfiguration that led to such problems.

Comment: @ZyX perhaps, I was just doing `brew install zsh` - I think.